# TextFile encryption in .Net framework and being able to decrypt under linux

Tags: .net, linux, file, encryption

I'm trying to find a solution to encrypt / decrypt text files from a .Net framework application with the constraint of being able to decrypt the file under linux ideally by a command line.

I just want to use a passphrase for the encryption (no public/private key).

I've tried to use ChoPGP (https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoPGP) but it use public/private keys what I don't want.

Have an idea ?

Comment: Pretty much any symetric algorithm will do, in .NET there are many of them already implemented, and on the Linux environment you can simply make another program with the same one, reading from a common file format.

Comment: OK I understand.

Comment: In fact what I need is to encrypt my file with something like AES-256 in C# and then I could decode the encoded file under linux with openssl. I'm right?

Comment: If you explicitly need to decrypt with OpenSSL you need to write a file format that matches exactly what it expect (otherwise it won't understand the input). The easiest part, if you want those constraints, is to just use OpenSSL at the encryption end too and don't code anything, given that it's multiplatform.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution to my problem.
I use the nuget BouncyCastle to encrypt/decrypt files with OpenPGP using a passphrase for the encryption. It works fine.